# Win10 Guest cannot ping Ubuntu host on VMWARE player over bridged wireless network interface

Tags: ubuntu, networking, vmware

I have a Win10 guest and a VMWARE Ubuntu 18.04 host (using VMWARE Player 15.5.0).
If I open command prompt on Win10 I cannot ping Ubuntu that has an address within the Win10 wireless network.
Ubuntu host is perfectly able to ping other hosts in the wireless network and I can ping the Ubuntu from another PC in the wireless network as well.

Very strange!!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to remove a filter called "LiveQoS NDIS 6 Filter Driver" on the wireless network interface on Win10 (go to Properties of wireless card).

In this way the ping started to work.